# What experiments don't confirm Poincare group-based representation of particle behavior

Tags: representation-theory, models

What experiments don't confirm Poincare group-based representation of particle behavior?

Sources:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group

Comment: Both those articles are fairly explicit and they both come with a set of proper references, but I don't find any statement along the lines of "not all experiments confirm ...". Can you be more explicit about what you want clarified?

Comment: I want to learn if there exist any (if yes, what) experiments that show that the representation in question fails to describe particle's behavior?

Comment: Did you recognize the statements in those article that limit the applicability of these groups to only certain classes of particles? Did you understand what those particles are? It really feels like you are asking for other people to do a lot of work for you when the answers are *right there in the articles you link*.

Comment: dmckee,if these are all such examples, then I'm okay with your answer. I wanted to make sure that the sources I provided cover my question.